# How do I show that something is loading like: loading. loading.. loading

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating rock paper scissors and I want to show that it's comparing hands with the 3 dots loading

`Example:
0s = Comparing Hands.
0.2s = Comparing Hands..
0.4s = Comparing Hands...`

and basically repeat that in a loop

https://pastecode.xyz/view/408bfc08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to do that.

Start an interval before evaluating the result. Then after evaluation clear the interval.

Inside the interval function display `"Comparing Hands..."` text with varying number of dots in the ellipsis.

**Live Example:**

```js
const compareHands = () => {

  const winner = document.querySelector(".winner");

  var i = 1;

  var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    winner.textContent = "Comparing Hands";

    i = i % 3;

    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      winner.textContent += "."
    }

    i++;
  }, 200);


  setTimeout(() => {
    // Code
  
    winner.textContent = "It is a tie";

    // Code

    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, 5000);
};

compareHands();
```

```html
<p class="winner"></p>
```